PySpark NOT_COLUMN_OR_STR Exception on Disconnected List
I am getting an odd pyspark exception when attempting to use filter and lambda functions on a list of ints I've collected from a pyspark dataframe, which makes no sense as the data exists in memory as a list and should be completely disconnected from pyspark. Here is the scenario.
I have a method that takes a dataframe and a column name and converts the values in the given column to a unique list of values. See below:
def collectListItems(dfData:DataFrame, fieldToCollect:str) -> list:
    dfData = dfData.groupby(fieldToCollect).count().select(fieldToCollect).collect()
    valueList = [f[fieldToCollect] for f in dfData]
    return valueList

I sometimes use this when I need to hold onto a list of Ids for operation in other tables after I've deleted data from a datasource or if I'm looking to determine the differences between two sets of data. This method has been working fine for months for a variety of different use cases.
Today, I was trying to take a different approach to getting the delta between two tables. Essentially, I have a customers table and a calls table (which has a FK reference to customers). I wanted to find any customers who have existed for more than x months in our system but haven't had any calls logged in more than y months. Not a particularly difficult problem and I have a few different approaches to solving this.
However, I wanted to try something new so I used the above method to collect all the customerIds created more than x months ago and a second list was collected that had all of the customerIds with calls in the last 6 months:
_createDate = date.today() + relativedelta(months=-12)
_archiveDate = date.today() + relativedelta(months=-6)
dfCustomers = spark.read.table('customers') \
                   .where(col('createdOn') < _createDate) \
                   .alias('cust')

dfActiveCalls = spark.read.table('calls') \
                     .where(col('calledOn') > _archiveDate) \
                     .alias('c')

dfActiveCustomers = dfActiveCalls.join(dfCustomers, col('c.customerId') == col('cust.customerId)', 'inner') \
                                 .select(col('cust.CustomerId'), col('c.callId')) \
                                 .groupBy('customerId') \
                                 .agg(count('callId').alias('totalCalls'))

currentCustomers = collectListItems(dfCustomers, 'customerId')
activeCustomers = collectListItems(dfActiveCustomers, 'customerId')


At this point, currentCustomers and activeCustomers are now python lists. I double checked their type (print(type(currentCustomers)) returns <class 'list'>) and the data is definitely a list of Ids (print(currentCustomers) returns [1, 5, 8, 16, 43...]). So at this point, the assumption is that the data is now stored in memory as a python list and no longer reliant on or tied to pyspark in any way. However, when I try the following:
inactiveCustomers = list(filter(lambda x: all(y not in x for y in activeCustomers), currentCustomers ))

I get the following exception:
 [NOT_COLUMN_OR_STR] Argument `col` should be a Column or str, got function.
 ----> 1 inactiveCustomers = list(filter(lambda x: all(y not in x for y in activeCustomers), currentCustomers))
 File /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py:66, in _to_java_column(col)
      64     jcol = _create_column_from_name(col)
      65 else:
 ---> 66     raise PySparkTypeError(
      67         error_class="NOT_COLUMN_OR_STR",
      68         message_parameters={"arg_name": "col", "arg_type": type(col).__name__},
      69     )
      70 return jcol

I am able to work around the problem by simply taking a different approach, but I'm curious as to why a pyspark exception is being thrown when executing code that involves no pyspark component. If those lists are truly stored as in memory lists in python, the exception makes no sense. It's almost as if the lists aren't truly being loaded into memory and are still being lazily evaluated by pyspark. But I thought collect() forces evaluation and loads the data into memory. Is that not the case? Why is pyspark throwing this exception?

Can you instead add simple inputs and expected outputs? That way is much easier to solve the problem. /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py contradicts with: "a pyspark exception is being thrown when executing code that involves no pyspark component."

That's kind of the point of my post. It's throwing a pyspark exception on a piece of code that SHOULD be completely disconnected from pyspark. I've initiated a .collect() on my dataframe and converted the contents into a list. Yet when I try to use the built in python filter, it's acting as though the .collect() never happened and is still trying to treat the list as a dataframe.
